# Нужно ли запускать npm install, если все пакеты установлены заранее?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, npm

Нужно апдейтнуть проект на компах с запретом выхода в сеть. Все `npm` пакеты уже установлены, будет производиться только замена исполняющего кода. 
Вопрос:
Можно ли будет обойтись бе запуска команды `npm install`? ведь при этом, как я понимаю, будет обращение в интернет, доступа к которому нет. Нормально ли подтянутся зависимости?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под *будет производиться только замена исполняющего кода*. Что за исполняющий код?

Comment: Если новых пакетов нет и версии не обновлялись (относительно той версии что установлена), то все будет ок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не требуется обновления, и все необходимые для работы приложения пакеты на месте (удовлетворены все зависимости), то **все будет работать как надо**.

Если вы запустите `npm install` без доступа к интернет, ничего не произойдет, `npm` выдаст ошибку подключения.

Конечно, нужно учитывать, что и окружение сервера тоже "совпадает" и соответствует требованиям приложения. Некоторые из пакетов могут использовать какие-либо библиотеки или например скомпилированные версии для определенной архитектуры.

> на заметку: можно использовать свой локальный сервер для дистрибуции пакетов [например](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia). Можно использовать пакеты из [локальных директорий](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)